# SQL query for getting next record value in previous row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, asp-classic

i have this table for example:

```
| prid  |  qty  | price |
| ----- |   1   |   20  |
| ----- |   7   |   18  |
| ----- |   12  |   15  |
| ----- |   20  |   12  |
```

and this SQL query:

```
prcrSql = "SELECT scaleqty, fld01, dim2, dim1, prcrule, finaldate FROM prcrdata WHERE finaldate>=getDate()-1 AND (dim1=30 OR dim1=40) ORDER BY dim2"
prcrRS.Open prcrSql

WHILE NOT prcrRS.EOF

insPRCR = "INSERT INTO prcr (mtrl,ofprice,minqty,maxqty,client,prcrule,fdate) VALUES ('"&prcrRS("dim2")&"','"&prcrRS("fld01")&"','"&prcrRS("minqty")&"','"&?????&"','"&prcrRS("dim1")&"','"&prcrRS("prcrule")&"','"&prcr("prdate")&"')"
myCon.Execute insPRCR

prcrRS.MoveNext
WEND
```

in the table above (image table) i have only the minqty (minimum quantity) and i want to set the maxqty (maximum quantity) 1 less than minqty of the next record.
for example at row 1: 4 (5-1)
at row 2: 7 (8-1)
and so on...

i want this result:

```
| prid  |  minqty  | maxqty | price |
| ----- |   1      |   6    |   20  |
| ----- |   7      |   11   |   18  |
| ----- |   12     |   19   |   15  |
| ----- |   20     |   -    |   12  |
```

how i can do this with SQL or classic ASP or PHP;
thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you define "next record"? your `SELECT` statement uses `ORDER BY dim2`, but I don't see `dim2` in your examples.

Comment: in Oracle this would be a LEAD or LAG function.  Might be a clue for other solutions.

Comment: the dim2 is the product ID. is auto_increment.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.prid, t1.qty AS minqty, MIN(t2.qty)-1 AS maxqty, t1.price
FROM prcr t1
LEFT JOIN prcr t2 ON t2.qty > t1.qty
GROUP BY t1.qty
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14e3e/3)

If the table is very large, performance of that may be poor. This should be faster:

```
SELECT prid, qty AS minqty, @maxqty AS maxqty, price, @maxqty := qty-1
FROM prcr
CROSS JOIN (select @maxqty := null) var
ORDER BY minqty DESC
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14e3e/4)

In either case, make sure you have an index on `qty`.

UPDATE:

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
prcrSql = "SELECT p1.scaleqty AS minqty, MIN(p2.scaleqty)-1 AS maxqty, p1.fld01, p1.dim2, p1.dim1, p1.prcrule, p1.finaldate 
           FROM prcrdata p1
           LEFT JOIN prcrdata p2 ON p1.fld01 = p2.fld01 AND p2.scaleqty > p1.scaleqty AND p2.finaldate>=getDate()-1 AND (p2.dim1=30 OR p2.dim1=40)
           WHERE p1.finaldate>=getDate()-1 AND (p1.dim1=30 OR p1.dim1=40)
           GROUP BY p1.scaleqty, p1.fld01, p1.dim2, p1.dim1, p1.prcrule, p1.finaldate
           ORDER BY dim2"
```

Here's a query that works with the subset data you posted:

```
SELECT p1.prid, p1.scaleqty AS minqty, MIN(p2.scaleqty)-1 AS maxqty, p1.price
FROM prcrdata p1
LEFT JOIN prcrdata p2 ON p2.scaleqty > p1.scaleqty AND p1.prid = p2.prid
GROUP BY p1.scaleqty, p1.prid, p1.price
ORDER BY p1.prid, p1.scaleqty
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9fcc8/4)

Comment: the table that i make the SELECT query is on MS SQL server and the table that i make the INSERT is on mySQL server. i can't join them.

Comment: My answer doesn't join different tables.

Comment: the table isnt't very large. but the tables are in different servers (inside in a same PC but the first is MS SQL and the second is MYSQL).

Comment: No `WHERE` clause is needed, the join condition is in the `ON` clause. It's joining the table with itself. I'm basing my answer on the table you showed at the top of the question, _I have this table for example_.

Comment: ok but i want to select only the records with this statements "finaldate>=getDate()-1 AND (dim1=30 OR dim1=40)". i don't want all of them. i can add them after the ON clause?

Comment: It looks to me like you do that when you're copying the rows from the MSSQL table to the MySQL table. You run my query _after_ that, to display the quantity ranges.

Comment: i must run my SELECT query first and then yours?

Comment: i have an error message "[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Column 'p1.SCALEQTY' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in an aggregate function and there is no GROUP BY clause."

Comment: it's working but in the first row of each item, the maxqty is 2. and the last row is 99 when the minqty is 50 or is 999 when the minqty is 500 etc...

example
70140 | 1 | 2 | 5.29
70140 | 10 | 19 | 4.375
70140 | 20 | 49 | 4.15
70140 | 50 | 99 | 3.95
85406 | 1 | 2 | 4.5
85406 | 10 | 19 | 4.05
85406 | 50 | 99 | 3.7
106694 | 1 | 2 | 0.169
106694 | 100 | 304 | 0.16
152089 | 305 | 914 | 0.14
152089 | 915 | 999 | 0.126

the last column is the price

Comment: Do you expect me to understand that unformatted table? Can you make a sqlfiddle with the input data?

Comment: I asked for the _input_ data so I can try to debug my query. If you want my help, please make it easy for me.

Comment: how i can give you the input data? the input data is like this without the maxqty column.

Comment: The query uses 6 columns, that page only has 4 columns, with no labels.

Comment: the other 2 columns are not necessary. they are specifying only if product is for retail or wholesale customers. the finaldate column is for offer expire. i want to set the maximum quantity to be 1 less than the next record minimum quantity.

Comment: see the new query I just added and the sqlfiddle